# How to protect request url against going upper in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to develope simple server in pure NodeJS for my own purposes. The problem I recently realized is that there is a little possibility to go upper or elsewhere from web on my local machine by adding something like `../../../` in path. My server looks like this:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(request, response) {
    var file_path = './web' + request.url;

    if (file_path == './web/')
        file_path = file_path + 'index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(file_path);

    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            content_type = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            content_type = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            content_type = 'application/json';
            break;
        default:
            content_type = 'text/html';
            break;
    }


    fs.readFile(file_path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(404);

            return response.end('Error loading ' + request.url);
        }

        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': content_type});

        return response.end(data);
    });
});
```

So I'm wondering what is the best way to protect from such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the root for your web files is `/web/files` and you want to make sure that no request outside that hierarchy is processed.  You can use `path.normalize()` to process all the `.` and `..` in it to then check the resulting path like this:

```
var path = require('path');

var file_path = '/web/files' + request.url;
var resolvedPath = path.normalize(file_path);
if (resolvedPath.indexOf('/web/files/') !== 0) {
    // illegal request
}
```

You can read about `path.normalize()` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p).  It resolves all `.` and `..` segements in a path so you can see what the real path will look like and then see if that is still a legal path.

---

Or, in a utility function:

```
var path = require('path');

function isPathContained(testPath, containerPath) {
    var resolvedPath = path.normalize(fullPath);
    return resolvedPath.indexOf(containerPath) === 0;
}
```

Then, you would use that like this:

```
var webFiles = '/web/files';
var file_path =  webFiles + request.url;
if (!isPathContained(file_path, webFiles)) {
    // illegal request
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this solution handles symlinks under /web/files to files and directories outside of that tree.  That's probably a reasonable tradeoff for situations where you can ensure there are no symlinks.

Comment: @DavePacheco - Correct, this doesn't prevent symlinks within the public tree from resolving to outside the tree,  But, if you put symlinks in your own public file tree, then that must be your own intent.  If you don't want symlinks in your own public tree, then obviously don't put them there.  So, I don't think any code to solve this problem needs to prevent symlinks from working.  `fs.realPath()` could be used to resolve even symlinks, though I don't think that extra step (and file system access) is required here since the target file system is controlled by the programmer.

Comment: Agreed, though using fs.realPath() to deal with this would introduce a race condition.

Comment: @DavePacheco - I'm not sure what you mean by a race condition.  If you have to worry about the directory hierarchy for your static files being changed out from under you while you're in the middle of using it, then you've got much bigger problems - fix your design so that is not a possibility.  That is clearly the better solution. `fs.realPath()` is async so using it would require an async design which is why you probably don't want to use it for a circumstance where it isn't needed as it complicates the use.

Comment: I think you understood the race -- it's between checking the path and then using the path. The problem isn't theoretical; people have developed exploits that make changes like this (say, if they have permission to create a symlink, but not read a file's contents) and then trick a privileged program into operating on the wrong file.  I agree that's likely not a consideration here, but the environment was not specified, and I think it's important to clarify the limitations of solutions.

Comment: @DavePacheco - Like I said, if an attacker has permission to create a symlink in your static files sub-directory on your web server, the problem should be fixed by denying that access, not by trying to protect from race conditions.  If you think a race condition-free solution using `realPath()` is relevant here, please post your own answer illustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Express.js Static Files](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for this.

Comment: As i wrote above i'm trying to do it in pure js.